# NoSuchElementException doesn't pass a test on Ideone

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

Please could you tell me what I did wrong. I think my code works correctly but doesn't pass a test on Ideone.

```
do{
    linia = reading.nextLine();
    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(linia);
        if(number < 100 && number > -100) {
                sum += number;
                resultList.add(sum);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        //System.out.println("Niepoprawne dane !");
        end = true;
    }
}while(!end);

if(resultList != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(resultList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: what its suppose to do ? and what your test is checking ?

Comment: data in:  for example : 12 10 3 data out: 12 22 25 - it must sum numbers

Comment: ok ,can you paste your test code as well which is failing?

Comment: could you open it? http://ideone.com/PL5WMZ

Comment: yup , looking at code

Comment: in local system , you are passing the input yourself , but in IDEONE it cant be possible , hence its failing.

Comment: so i must choose random numbers ?

Comment: you should remove the code, which ask user to put the numbers ... if you can provide random numbers yourself then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that in your code, you accept the input on command line from the user using code `linia = reading.nextLine();` which is not possible with the IDEONE (online editor) As there it can't supply the user input.

Thats the reason it was working fine locally but failing when you run it on IDEONE.

Removing the code, which ask user input will solve the issue.

Comment: In my request I must get data from user :( but you have right

Comment: then you can't test it on ideone, use some local IDE like intellij or eclipse or run your program on command-line, which interacts with users.